# I cannot embed a font in html page using @font-face rule

Tags: html, css, fonts

i have tried adding a font to my webpage using @font-face rule but its not showing

**HTML**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <ul>
    <li>GREAT</li>
    <li>BITE</li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

body{
font-family:Armata;
font-size:16px;
    color:orange;
text-align: center;
background:white;
}

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Armata';
    src: url(Armata-Regular.ttf),
    src: url(Armata-Regular.otf),
    src: url(Armata-Regular.eot);
    }
```

you can download the font from here : http://www.moldire.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to put font-face in top of CSS.

```
   @font-face {
        font-family: 'Armata';
        src: url(Armata-Regular.ttf),
        src: url(Armata-Regular.otf),
        src: url(Armata-Regular.eot);
        }
    body{
    font-family:Armata;
    font-size:16px;
        color:orange;
    text-align: center;
    background:white;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for realizing that the order is out of place.  +1

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Armata';
    src: url(Armata-Regular.ttf),
    src: url(Armata-Regular.otf),
    src: url(Armata-Regular.eot);
    }

li
{
font-family:Armata;
}
```

or if u want to use it for full page then apply it to body tag

Answer (score 0):

Here are my steps to have the font working:

- Font face first in css (already mentioned)
- Have the type/format of font -  EX:  `src: url(Armata-Regular.ttf) format('truetype')`
- Make sure your host (local or not) has the MIME type for these fonts

Lastly, would you consider a web font path? Save yourself time by getting a web path embedded font: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Armata

Doing this will save you time skipping last bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your website

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Armata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and in CSS you will need this :

```
    font-family: 'Armata', sans-serif;
```